# MVC 4 controller error after adding a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, azure, controller, runtime-error

I have deployed a MVC4 internet application to Azure successfully. I can then browse to the site and it is all working correctly.

I have then added a Book model and a Book controller. This works correctly on my localhost and I can add Book items.

I have then deployed this MVC4 internet application to Azure and I can browse to the home page with no errors.

However, I am getting an error when browsing to the Book controller.

This is the error that I am getting:

Error.

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

What would be causing this, and how can I get this controller page working? Can I get more information about this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to run with a wild stab in the dark and say your database connection strings will not be set correctly; which is why it's working locally but not on the cloud.

Eshan's answer will definitely let you drill into what's going on, though.

Comment: Thanks, the connection string was not set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is some exception coming in your application and your Remote Errors are turned off so its displaying **User Friendly Error Message**

Add these lines to your `web.config`, if you want the errors to be displayed what it is exactly:

```
<compilation debug="true"/>
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
```